# requestAnimationFrame, параметр time callback-a

Tags: javascript

Есть простой код

```js
let lastTime = performance.now();
const timer = function (rAFnow) {
    const delta = rAFnow - lastTime;
    console.log(lastTime, rAFnow, delta);

    lastTime = rAFnow;
    if(delta < 0) requestAnimationFrame(timer);
}

requestAnimationFrame(timer);
```

Вопрос заключается в том, почему/при каких обстоятельствах `lastTime` оказывается больше, чем `rAFnow`?

Comment: Если страница загрузилась быстрее чем диапозон вызова requestAnimationFrame,это 10-20мс +-

Comment: @Александр что такое _диапозон вызова requestAnimationFrame_?